# Looking for solution to summarize all "Alert Me" email within site collection into one

Tags: alert

The OOTB alert me allow end-users to subscribe for the list/libray or item he is interested in. The problem is when user subscribe for different lists under same site collection (as daily summary), he will receive more than 1 email at the day-end.

I am looking for solution to merge all "alert me" email into single email summary (for one site collection). Is the product or solution available? Thanks for information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this exactly what you looking for, but with [JungleBell from EnovaPoint](http://www.enovapoint.com/blog/post/JungleBell-Mail-Merge-SharePoint-Alerts-from-Multiple-Lists) you can mail merge alerts from multiple SharePoint lists using repeater feature. But it will not merge your existing OOTB alets, you will need to configure a new one with conditions to merge everything you want have in a one email.